# Dump and update RRD file in memory

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Is there a way to dump and update rrd file in memory. I know we can dump it as xml file and then read + update + restore it back as rrd. But this is not an efficient way for me as i may have to update/correct large amount of "old data"    [I refer this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11573983/1413892)

Its documentation pages talks about deamon address as a paramete, can i use this to udpate rrd data in memory ? How Do i read data from deamon ?

```
 rrdtool dump --daemon unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock /var/lib/rrd/foo.rrd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dump/restore via set of pipes, modifying the data using a filter program ...

```
rrdtool dump old.rrd - | filter | rrdtool restore - new.rrd
```

If you are intent on actually having the dumped version around, you could also dump to a tmpfs  partition.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, But before restoring the same rrd, i want to change few values in that. Can i do that ???